# Some confusion about Theory of Sets by Bourbaki

Tags: set-theory

On page 16 :

> "A *mathematical theory* contains rules which allow us to assert that certain assemblies of signs are *terms* or *relations* of the theory"

Originally, I simply regard 'rule' as manipulation on assembles with or without property (here 'manipulation' means operation which gain a new assemble, property means character which can be judged precisely). For instance, $\lor AB$. where $A,B$ represent two normal assemblies (without property), $\lor$ can be regard as an assemble with certain property which allow us to judge that general assemble if it is $\lor$.

On page 25 :

> "R results from the application of a scheme to terms or relations".

However, for S1 on page 28, '$\lor$' can't be term or relation.

In a word, I want to know the precise definition of "rule".

Comment: Why are you reading about set theory from Bourbaki?

Comment: "Confusion" and "Bourbaki" in the same title... Nice.

Comment: The book itself is fascinating.I realized that a mathematical assertion can reason from the sentences of theory without anything like geometrical or visual model. the general structure can be the faith of mathematician, from this point, bourbaki is Thomas Aquanas

Comment: Another question, could scheme involve explicit axioms? That is, manipulation on explicit axioms to gain relations, thus, substitute of theory can be ridiculous.

Comment: PS. Thanks for your replications to my first question!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you agree with the answer below that Enderton is the best alternative to Bourbaki?

Answer (score 6):

As Asaf says : "Why are you reading about set theory from Bourbaki ?".

In general, I think that Bourbaki is not a good point to start with regarding both set theory and mathematical logic.

In general, taken aside the "un-friendly" symbolism used by Bourbaki, the starting point for "formalizing" mathematics (as you can find in modern mathematical logic textbooks, like Herbert Enderton, *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* (2nd ed - 2001) ) are :

> a *language*, base on a finite set of symbols and rules (mechanically checkable) for building allowable *expressions*, tipically called *terms* and (well formed) *formulae* (Carnap called them "formation rules").

So, reading from the french edition of Nicolas Bourbaki, *Théorie des ensembles* (1970), your citation points at the definition of *term* (i.e. a "name" denoting an object of the "universe of discourse" of the *theory*; e.g. in number theory, $0$, $1$, ... are "names" for numbers) and *formula* (relation), an expression about the objects of the domain and their properties that has a definite meaning (e.g.in number theory, the sentence $0 < 1$, that is *true*).

See on page I.18 of french edition :

> " Intuitivement, les termes sont des assemblages qui représentent des objets, les relations sont des assemblages qui représentent des assertions que l'on peut faire sur des objets. "

The language of Bourbaki use only two *connectives* : $\lnot$ (negation) and $\lor$ (disjunction) [see page I.14] and define the *conditional* ($\Rightarrow$) in the usual truth-functional way [see page I.15].

What makes "terrible" the reading of Bourbaki, is the use of Hilbert's *epsilon* operator in place of quantifiers, where a term $\epsilon x A$ denotes some $x$ satisfying $A(x)$; see [epsilon calculus](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epsilon-calculus/), with the added difficulty due to the omission of bounded variables, replaced by a "square" as place-holder [see page I.16].

The second component of a formalized system is :

> a set of primitive *expressions* called *axioms* (like Euclid's postulates for geometry); we assume them as expressing "true facts" about the "universe of discourse" of our system (like $a + 0 = a$ in number theory).

The third component will be :

> a set (tipically one : *modus ponens*) of inference rules applicable to existing formulae to "produce" new formulae (Carnap called them "transformation rules").

With this machinery in place, you can have the fundamental definitions of :

> *derivation*, i.e. a finite sequence of formulae where each step is an axiom or is obtained from previous formulae in the sequence by use of the inference rules
>
> *theorem*, i.e. the last formula in a derivation.

So, a derivation is a (formal) proof in the system and a theorem is a formula that has been proved in the system starting from the axioms.

*Note.* The "$\lor$" is simply the *disjunction*; see page I.18 :

> *Remarque*. — La condition [...] b) signifie que, si $B$ est une assertion, $\lnot B$, qu'on appelle la *négation* de $B$, est une assertion (qui se lit: non $B$). La condition c) signifie que, si $B$ et $C$ sont des assertions, $\lor BC$, qu'on appelle la *disjonction* de $B$ et $C$, est une assertion:

Subsequently, $\lor$ "disappear" because Bourbaki introduces some useful abbreviations [page I.21] :

> "Pour faciliter la lecture de ce qui suit, nous écrirons désormais, si $A$ est une relation, non($A$) au lieu de $\lnot A$. Si $A$ et $B$ sont des relations, nous écrirons « ($A$) ou ($B$) » au lieu de $\lor AB$, et ($A$) $\Rightarrow$ ($B$) au lieu de $\Rightarrow AB$. Parfois, nous supprimerons les parenthèses. Le lecteur pourra déterminer sans peine [*sic !*], dans chaque cas, de quel assemblage il s'agit."

Comment: Note to OP: I strongly recommend both Enderton's "Mathematical Introduction to Logic" and "Elements of Set Theory"; both do good treatments of the elementary theory, while still treating the reader fairly gently.

Comment: @Russell Thomas - see the suggestion above by @Mike; it's a good one ! :)

Comment: well，I will always consult Enderton's books when I encounter promblems about logic and set theory! :)